# Workaround for snapshot versions in Npm

Tags: npm, snapshot

After searching on the net for solutions to simulate the behaviour of Maven snapshot versions in Npm, I have made some test and found a workaround that works to me.

I would like you to give me some feedback if you please, and let me know if you know of any other possible workarounds or if there is something I'm missing on this one.

The only downside I see is that the actual version of the installed dependency has to be checked in the `node_modules` folder, because I'm using `npm update --no-save` to avoid replacing my range expression in `package.json` after installs or updates.

You can find the code and doc in my [github](https://github.com/twopelu/how-npm3-works#workarround-for-snapshots-in-npm).

### Workaround for snapshots in Npm

#### Publish and use snapshot versions

Libraries:

1. (**only in first project setup**) Set version in `package.json` to:

   ```
   "version": "0.0.0-snapshot.0"
   ```
2. Use these command to publish snapshots and tag as *snapshot*:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "publish:snapshot": "npm run version:snapshot && npm publish --tag snapshot",
       "version:snapshot": "npm version prerelease --preid snapshot"
   }
   ```
3. Check that snapshot number is incremented in `package.json`

Application:

1. (**only in first project setup**) Delete `package-lock.json` and `npm install`
2. Set dependency to snapshot version in development:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "npm-test-lib-a": ">=0.0.0-snapshot.0"
   }
   ```
3. To get the latest snapshot version use this command:

   ```
   npm update <package> --no-save
   ```
4. To see version actually installed see `node_modules`

#### Publish and use release versions

Libraries:

1. Use these commands to publish releases and tag as *latest*:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "publish:release": "npm run version:release && npm publish",
       "version:release": "npm version 1.0.0"
   }
   ```
2. Always set version back to **snapshot** after publishing a release

Application:

1. To get the latest release version use npm install:

   ```
   npm install <package>
   ```
2. To see version actually installed see `node_modules`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the closest behaviour possible is with [Workspaces in Npm 7](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces).

Comment: workspaces simplify the app <--> library dependency management, but I have yet no idea how to handle snapshots in npm. I am considering git hooks. Have you figured out another approach?

Comment: I leverage the CI/CD pipeline to generate 0.0.0-dev-* prereleases with incremental version numbers (dev-1, dev-2, ..). But nothing as good as Maven snapshots but it does the trick. This should be a "must have" in NPM and any package manager to me.

Comment: And of course this does not solve the problem of dependency resolution with local and remote repositories, which is just perfect in Maven and it makes you much more productive. The only option in NPM is using npm pack or nmp link in local which is a shame.